# Audio cache for small files android studio

Tags: java, android, caching, audio, mobile

I am developing a soundboard application in which I need to get the specified audio file from the server when the user requests it, but I don't want to stream it or download it every time, just the first time so I was thinking of caching it someway.

I made some research and I found the ExoPlayer library from google but I think it's kinda overkill for my purpose and I can't seem to get my head around it as I'm not so experienced in android development.

Is there any library that I can use?

If not, how can I make the process myself?

Answer (score 0):

Save it to the file system the first time.  Then you never have to download it again.

Comment: But isn't it more efficient to cache them?

Comment: That is caching them.  Cache means to store a local copy.  There's multiple levels you can cache at.  No caching would require downloading from the net every time, very slow-  up to several seconds, uncompressed file size in RAM but only when using it.  Disk caching requires reading from the disk.  Somewhat slow-  a few ms and memory only when using it.  Keeping the file in memory (memory caching)-  several nanoseconds, but also requires permanent to semi permanent memory usage, and if it falls out of the cache you need to either read from disk or download again.

Comment: So if you're looking to avoid downloading only-  cache to disk and never download again.  If you're looking to speed up your app to maximum and are willing to pay the memory penalty, cache in memory.  There's also use cases for doing both-  caching to disk for long term storage and memory for immediate uses.

Comment: Oh I understand now, but is there a difference between downloading all the sounds, saving them in the file system or just having them in the raw folder from the beginning? Which is more efficient memory-wise.